# How to use For-Each loop in JavaScript to make an object, whose Keys and values are dynamically provided?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to make a JavaScript object in the following form, where the Car Make and Model Names supplied from other variables.

```
{  
   "Sedan":{  
      "Jaguar":[  
         "XF",
         "XJ"
      ],
      "AUDI":[  
         "A6",
         "A4"
      ]
   }
}
```

the object should be formed using the below variables:

var type="sedan" (An object of sedan type) 
var makes=["Jaguar","AUDI"]; (All makes of Sedan type in this array)
var modelList=[{"make":"Jaguar","models":["XF","XJ"]},{"make":"AUDI","models":"A6","A4"}] (All the models of a particular make)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you seem to have made one already `{"Sedan":{"Jaguar":["XF","XJ"],"AUDI":["A6","A4"]}}` congratulations

Comment: I just need to make a json object in the mentioned format.

Comment: What is the data you're provided with? Which should be converted to JSON?
If it is already an object, there are probably built-in functions to convert... what language do you use?

Comment: you already have it..

Comment: @LionC Question is more clear now.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves sorry my question was incomplete then. Please let me know if it is more clear now.

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest I just added the data which I need to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. I have used `forEach` method for iteration. The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element. You may use any iteration techniques like `for`, `while`, etc.. instead.

```js
var type = "sedan";
var makes = ["Jaguar", "AUDI"];
var modelList = [{
    "make": "Jaguar",
    "models": ["XF", "XJ"]
}, {
    "make": "AUDI",
    "models": ["A6", "A4"]
}];

var object = {};
object[type] = {}; //object becomes { "sedan": {} }
makes.forEach(function(make) {
    object[type][make] = []; //In 1st iteration object becomes { "sedan": { "Jaguar": [] }}
    modelList.forEach(function(model) {
        if (model.make == make) {
            object[type][make] = model.models; //In 1st iteration object becomes { "sedan": { "Jaguar": ["XF","XJ"] }} 
        }
    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: You'r welcome Joseph :)

Comment: Hi Gilsha if the modelList is in the format var modelList = [{
    "make": "Jaguar",
    "models": "XF"
}, {
    "make": "Jaguar",
    "models": "XJ"
},{
 "make": "AUDI",
    "models": "A6"
},{
 "make": "AUDI",
    "models": "A4"
}];
How can I get the desired output?

Comment: In that case, you will have to update the line `object[type][make] = model.models;` with `object[type][make].push(model.models);`

Comment: Thank you very much Gilsha.... You are a genius...

Answer (score -1):

Given object:

```
var object = {  
"Sedan":{  
  "Jaguar":[  
     "XF",
     "XJ"
  ],
  "AUDI":[  
     "A6",
     "A4"
  ]
}
}
```

You can make it a JSON string using:

```
var json = JSON.stringify( object );
```

Comment: Each of the values are dynamic, not static. It is formed using the mentioned variables